# Select records only if another record contains a value from the first record in different field

Tags: mysql

I haven't had any luck trying to figure this out or what type of statement would be involved if it's possible.

I'm dealing with a company standard 'employees' db.   The db has fields for USER_ID and SUPERVISOR_ID.  There are no fields to indicate if an employee is a supervisor or if they have subordinates.  The only way to know if an employee has subordinates is if any other record has the employee's USER_ID in it's SUPERVISOR_ID field.

I need first_name / last_name based query that only returns employees that have subordinates.

```
SELECT * from employees e 
WHERE e.first_name LIKE '%<first_name_string>%' 
AND e.last_name LIKE '%<last_name_string>%'
```

`*(and where at least one record lists this USER_ID in it's SUPERVISOR_ID field`)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * from employees e 
WHERE e.first_name LIKE '%<first_name_string>%' 
AND e.last_name LIKE '%<last_name_string>%' 
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE employees.SUPERVISOR_ID = e.USER_ID) > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from employees e
where e.first_name LIKE '%firstnamestring%'
AND e.last_name LIKE '%lastnamestring%'
AND (e.USER_ID in
(select SUPERVISOR_ID from employees))
```

Try this.